# Wrong scroll to anchor with owl-carousel before anchor section

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I use this script to scroll down to a certain anchor when page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#myanchor').offset().top
    }, 100);
});
```

Anyway, before this #myanchor there are 2 sections containing 2 different owl-carousel. The scroll goes to the wrong position when page loads. It goes aproximately over the secon owl-carousel.

I suppose that it's caused by a wrong calculation of the window height because at the first moment the carousel are loaded have an height equal to 0. I just suppose that.
I don't want to assign a minimum or fixed height to those section. So, there's a solution? Maybe a little delay in scroll down? Could someone suggest me the code that could help me solve this issue?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to add an event listener for the images to finish loading. But we developers have timelines to get stuff done.  So, just use a timeout to give the carousel time to load. In most cases, users need time to absorb your content so you have a few seconds before they click on anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.

    setTimeout( function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#myanchor').offset().top
        }, 100);
    }, 3500);
});
```

Comment: I've also tested it with timeout to 0 and seems works to, I don't know why.